# How to remove Blank Rows using EPPlus Excel Package Plus

Tags: c#, .net, epplus, excelpackage

I'm using EPPlus 4.1.0.0, and I want to convert my excel sheet into a datatable.

There are few empty rows at the end of the excel file.

So while converting it, I am also getting the empty rows into datatable.

How do I remove the empty rows before converting it to a datatable?

Comment: What does you code look like?  Empty cells usually mean they contain whitespace like null length strings.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49232456/1114531

It is checking the last row if it is empty and if yes it deletes it and doing this until finds non-empty row. (non-empty means here: all columns in this row have some value)

Answer (score -1):

You could use `DeleteRow`

```
 worksheet.DeleteRow(lastRow + 1, worksheet.Dimension.End.Row - lastRow - 1);
```

Comment: What about checking if the row is actually empty before?